# Ubuntu and Hp pavilion 15e069sl

Tags: drivers, hp

does wi-fi connection works on Hp pavilion 15e069sl if i install the latest version of ubuntu on it?
if it doesn't work where can I find the drivers to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to evaluate if your system is compatible with Ubuntu is to boot from a liveCD/USB. Just burn the .iso image file to a DVD, boot-up your system and see what happens :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got a pavilion and I had the same problem.
You're right! The newer Kernel does support the wifi-module. You simply have to install the latest release of [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).